# "Android application" is stopped

Tags: java, android

I am following thenewboston's tutorials (Android application development) but the app I made is crashed after running one class(splash) file.

After splash class, menu class is to run and then MainActivity, followed by textplay..

I am writing a code for all classes. See if you can find what's wrong here

Splash class

```
 package com.example.testing;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this,R.raw.sound);
        ourSong.start();
        Thread timer=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent openStartingPoint=
                              new Intent("com.example.testing.Menu");

                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                }
                    }
    };timer.start();
}
    protected void onPause(){
                super.onPause();
                ourSong.release();
                finish();
                }
}
```

Menu Class

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[]={"MainActivity","TextPlay","example2","example3","example4","example5"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese=classes[position];
        try {
             Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.testing."+ cheese);
            Intent ourIntent=new Intent(Menu.this , ourClass);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }





}
```

MainActivity Class

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add,sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter=0;
    add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            counter++;
            display.setText("Your Total is "+ counter);

        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your Total is "+counter);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

TextPlay Class

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class TextPlay extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text);

        Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bResults);
        final ToggleButton passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById (R.id.tbPassword);
        EditText input =(EditText) findViewById (R.id.etCommands);
        TextView display = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvResults);
        passTog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(passTog.isChecked()){

                }
                else{
                    }
                }
        });
    }



}
```

Comment: post your error log here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent("com.example.testing.Menu");
```

Instead of this use  -

```
 Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanxx it worked after changing just this.

Comment: Can you explain what was the problem with above line of code because of which App was stopping ?

Comment: The constructor Intent(String action) is used for creating intent for actions like,Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

May be you will get `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException` here `Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent("com.example.testing.Menu");` change your **finally** like below

```
finally{
        Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
        startActivity(openStartingPoint);
}
```